# Question about sending requests with Eth Address

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, graphql, metamask

I have a problem. Recently I have been working on Web3 app with database just to set a ...Username for a user. The problem is that the user can edit request I'm sending and maybe switches to Address of someone like Elon Musk(for example) and edits his name. I was scrolling on opensea and found out that they just send a request like that when changing the username:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECSnw.png

Someone can just change the address and change the name of Elon Musk(for example). How they do it so the user can just change username of address that he owns and not from anyone other.

Answer (score 0):

The TL;DR answer is: You can NEVER trust data coming from the client-side. The code on the server must validate everything.

The code on the server should identify if the request it received is from an authenticated user (i.e. the user has logged in and has a valid token). If the user is "authenticated", then you proceed to determine if they are "authorized" (have permissions) to perform the action or view the requested data. Finally, if they are authenticated (who they are) and authorized (permissions they have), you still must validate and sanitize any data you get from them. Whatever makes sense for your service.

This is all a lot of work, and it's easy to make mistakes. This is the reason you adopt a well tested library and learn how to use it. It will do much of the work for you, and then you only need to worry about the areas that apply to your project. For example, is it OK if the the "Name" is already in use by someone else, or does it need to be unique. Is bad language OK, or should be rejected, etc.

For more details, look into [OWASP Broken Access Control](https://owasp.org/Top10/A01_2021-Broken_Access_Control/).